# Portable Class Library best practices

Tags: .net, portability

I am converting some .NET framework targeted projects over to Portable Class Libraries and looking for some best practices.

Usually all of my projects use the same project name and assembly name, and that name is also the base for all namespaces used within the project. If my project name is Project.Name.Whatever, should I include the word "Portable" in my new project name? (ie. Project.Name.Whatever.Portable) ...and have that be the assembly name and base namespace as well?

If the library is being put on nuget should I define separate packages or include both DLLs in one package with different targets?

If the code doesn't change when converting from one project to the other, do I even need the original project. Can't everything just move over to the portable project and everything that references the old project can safely be updated to the portable project? (even nuget references?)

What other best practices should I be aware of? All I can find online about PCLs is how to create them, nothing on best practices.

Comment: Can someone create the tag "portable-class-library" and tag this?

Comment: ProjectName.Whatever.Portable seems questionable.  There are many whatever's.  There is one portable.  Packages should organize code.  They shouldn't be comments.  Consider ProjectName.Portable.Whatever

Answer (score 2):

> If the code doesn't change when converting from one project to the other, do I even need the original project. Can't everything just move over to the portable project and everything that references the old project can safely be updated to the portable project? (even nuget references?)

The above question is the answer to the question below.

> If my project name is Project.Name.Whatever, should I include the word "Portable" in my new project name? (ie. Project.Name.Whatever.Portable) ...and have that be the assembly name and base namespace as well?

If code doesn't change then why are you dragging around the old version?  You've simply added a portability requirement you didn't have before.  Unless you have a simultaneous requirement to not be portable ditch the old stuff by releasing a new portable version.  Then you can brag: Portable since version 3.1415